# using laravel migrations to access tables already created

Tags: laravel, model, migration, setter, getter

I have some tables that are already created in the database. The migrations seem to require that you first destroy the table and then create it. From what I understand, the creation process generates a "model" at the same time as well as "getters" and "setters" for the fields.

The problem is that I have a database full of tables already. I would like to access the tables that have already been created using Laravel as an interface. Is there a way to generate a model, getters and setters for tables that already exist?

How can I best do this?
TIA

Comment: you can delete unwanted table manually from database and than also remove table  from mingrations in your created database. then you can command php artisan migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default model generator doesn't create any getters or setters. All it does is create a basic model class with the correct model name based on the table name. You can create the models without actually creating the migration. The command is `php artisan make:model ModelName`.

So the answer to your question is no, there isn't any. You need to manually create each model and add the methods yourself. You might try your luck with some laravel package which might do this for you.

Note : Laravel Eloquent is an ActiveRecord implementation. You don't need any getters or setters to work with the table columns. Even a completely empty model with the correct name to match the table would be enough to start using Eloquent.

Comment: yes, thanks - I saw that. Unfortunately, the tables I have do not use "id", "created..." and "updated ..." fields (which the "model" seems to depend upon).

Comment: @CaseyHarrils not really. You can tell the model that you do not have the default timestamp fields by adding `protected $timestamps = false;`. You can also have models without a primary key and if you have a custom key then specify it in the model with `protected $primaryKey = 'custom_id';`. It's very flexible.